# How can I quickly turn all objects of a layer to independent layers in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

How can I quickly turn all objects of a layer (text boxes, shapes, lines, etc.) to independent layers in InDesign ?

Answer (score 1):

This tiny script should do what you want:

```
#target InDesign

var doc = app.activeDocument;

for (var i = 1; i < doc.pageItems.length; i++) {
  var newLayer = doc.layers.add();
  doc.pageItems[i].itemLayer = newLayer;
}
```

For each page item it finds in the document, it creates a new layer and moves the item to the new layer.

Edit: As you actually need all objects of a *layer* to move to new layers, not all objects of the *doc*, the script would look like this instead:

```
#target InDesign

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var myLayer = doc.layers.item("Your layer's name");

for (var i = myLayer.pageItems.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
  var newLayer = doc.layers.add();
  myLayer.pageItems[i].itemLayer = newLayer;
}
```