# Place every object from a single layer to a new layer in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

is there a possibility to place every object automatically from one single layer into different new layers in InDesign?

Thanks!

Comment: Not very clear what you're asking. Edit and add more detail, an image maybe?

Comment: @Lucian then why not vote to close?

Comment: I feel i can help with this but not really sure what to answer at this point.

Comment: @Lucian Andreas, I think this has been already asked and answered here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81678/how-can-i-quickly-turn-all-objects-of-a-layer-to-independent-layers-in-indesign/81688#81688 So you should be able to use the script in the answer to do what you want.

Comment: @mdomino Thanks for your tip! The script is working, but the output of the layers is not in the same order as the objects are in the layer. I have too much layers to sort it by hand.

Comment: @Lucian Thank you too. Is it now clear for you? Do you have a solution to sort the layers in the right order?

Comment: Is this referring to a single page document? Else how would you determine the order of page items, if they are on different pages?

Comment: Yes, it is a single page with a single layer (it's a webpage design). After i have the different layers, i want to use the script from zenodesign.com to open the file (including the layers) in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should work for a single page scenario. It splits up all your top level page items into layers and should keep them in the correct order:

```
// @target InDesign

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var page = doc.layoutWindows[0].activePage;

var items = page.allPageItems.reverse();

for (var i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
  if(!(items[i].parent.constructor.name === "Spread")) continue;

  var newLayer = doc.layers.add();
  items[i].itemLayer = newLayer;
}
```

Comment: If this answer solves your issue, please accept the given answer, so others can see it solved your issue.